# Recover source code for C# .exe

Tags: decompile, c#

I paid a freelancer programmer for an app to tun my clinic. He got about 95% of the project done, but then got a job elsewhere and vanished into thin air, along with my source code... So, I have a semi-working program and I need to finish it. How can I recover the source code (Visual Studio, C#) to a point I can finish what I need and then recompile it again? Is this possible? I'm willing to buy/pay...

Comment: .NET Reflector is the best. I've used ILSpy to a similar degree of success before as well.

Comment: Have you considered asking him for the source code? I know you said he vanished in thin air but you may have a chance considering you paid him, depending on what you agreed for him to build.

Comment: No. He's off the radar. I haven't been able to even locate him or a phone number.

Comment: My question: with Reflector, can I end up with the original source code in a way I can finish the coding of the missing items and recompile again?

Comment: you can't recover "the original source code" (e.g. comments and often variable names are lost completely during compilation) but for C# it should be possible to recover "equivalent code" which should let you add the missing functionality yourself.

Answer (score 5):

As far as free and open source tools go, I'd recommend [dnSpy](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy). It is the best tool I've used for .NET reverse engineering.

You might also want to try out [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/), which is free and open source as well.

Comment: My question: with Reflector, can I end up with the original source code in a way I can finish the coding of the missing items and recompile again?

Comment: dnSpy allows you to edit the code. So you should be able to add what you need. I never did try to get the entire source as files, though.

Answer (score 4):

Consider also [JetBrains dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) that is free, decompiles .NET 1.0-4.5 assemblies to C#.

Has support for .dll, .exe, .zip, .vsix, .nupkg, and .winmd files.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question "Can I end up with the original source code in a way I can finish the coding of the missing items and recompile again?": if it runs on your system, it means you have all the dependencies needed and you'll be able to decompile to a state where you can edit and recompile at will.

I don't know about Reflector, but with ILSpy, you have the option in the File menu to "Save as..." and you can save a .csproj or a .vbproj (this can be done because the intermediate language of .Net can round-trip to both languages; so even if coding was in C#, you can roundtrip to VB if you wanted).

Answer (score 2):

There are many free and paid utilities out there that aim to decompile .NET applications.

Personally I use [.NET Reflector](https://www.red-gate.com/dynamic/products/dotnet-development/reflector/download) - which is a commercial application with a 14-day free evaluation version.

Comment: My question: with Reflector, can I end up with the original source code in a way I can finish the coding of the missing items and recompile again?

Comment: Yes, assuming the code wasn't packed or obfuscated. (It probably wasn't)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple free/Trial tools available 
Personally i used .NET Reflector and JustDecompile With JustDecompile you can Edit your source code as well