# Deconstructing Unity games

Tags: decompilation, game-hacking

*Note: I only want to edit/mod the games not trying to steal things etc.*

---

I'm trying to deconstruct some Unity games from both PC and Android platforms and already extracted assets with uTinyRipper successfully, but having the some issues at the script part.

**What exactly should i do to export scripts correctly from a compiled Unity game to editor?**

---

**Firstly** I deobfuscate everything in data\managed with de4dot

**Secondly** I extract the code from these .dlls with dnSpy

**Then** I import all the .cs files to Unity editor

**After that**, Unity gives hundreds/thousands of errors, when i fix all of them, it gives another hundreds of errors. So it doesn't stop giving more errors.

Comment: Do you have exactly the same Unity version that was used to build the game? Did you switch to the right platform in Build settings?

Comment: Yes i tried using the same version that was used to build the game. Hadn't touched build settings though

Comment: Have you tried building a Unity project and deconstruct the build back to Unity project? That could help you learn how to fix common issues.

Comment: Thats a very good idea, i will try that. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recover source code for C# .exe](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12874/recover-source-code-for-c-exe)